# HammerJS continuous dragging (drag after release)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, hammer.js

Can I achieve dragging after release with HammerJS (and how...)? (I use it alongside AngularJS but that shouldn't matter)

The reason I am asking is that I want to achieve smooth scrolling (like native iOS continued scrolling after release of the finger)

I am sure this can be done somehow because there is a velocity property in the event of the gesture.

my code has a overlay div on top of my content that detects the touches, and then I do manual control of the scrolling of the divs below based on that.

Answer (score 2):

You'll just need to set up your own velocity callback on panend. Something like the below should work (assuming using Hammer v2)

```
    var friction = -0.05;

    function panend(evt) {
        applyVelocity(evt.velocityY,evt.direction);
    }

    function applyVelocity(v,dir) {
        var dist = v*16;
        if(dir===Hammer.DIRECTION_DOWN) {
            dist*=-1;
        }

        //code here to move your elements Y transform

        if(v>0) {
            v+=friction;
            window.requestAnimationFrame(function(){
                applyVelocity(v,dir);
            });
        }
    }
```

Comment: I'm new to hammer.js and animating -- why does friction make sense? and why is velocity involved? how does this make the animation smoother?